# Calcular en JS números positivos con condiciones

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear dos funciones para que lean un array y devuelvan valores true o false.

Un array de tiempos de llegada tarde. Por ejemplo, uno llegó 10 minutos tarde, otro 5 minutos antes, otro 3 minutos tarde, y otro puntual:

```
var ingresosDelLunes = [10, -5, 3, 0];
```

Con esta información y un mínimo de dos personas la función es True. Por ejemplo, el lunes se abre, porque hubo una llegada puntual y una temprano

Necesito saber:

- seAbre, que dice si se hace una clase dado el array de ingresos (ya esta solucionado)
- aperturas, que toma un array con los arrays de ingresos de varios días, y la cantidad mínima de estudiante, y diga que dias se abrió y que días no.
  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  aperturas([ingresosDelLunes, ingresosDelMartes, ingresosDelMiercoles], 2)
  ```

  [true, false, false]

Hoy por hoy tengo esto (gracias a la ayuda de la comunidad), pero no sé como continuar con la segunda función:

Se tiene que cumplir esto:

```
 aperturas([[0, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 3) 
 aperturas([[0, 0, -3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 4)


function seAbre(arr, limite){
//Variable que contabiliza los que han llegado puntual o pronto
var cantidad = 1;
            //Recorrer el array
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                //Si el valor es 0 o menor ha llegado puntual o antes de tiempo
                if (arr[i] <= 2){
                    //Sumamos 1 al numero de personas que ha llegado bien
                    cantidad = cantidad + 1;
                }
            }
            //En función de la gente que necesites devolvemos true or false
            if (cantidad > limite) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si he entendido bien lo que necesitas hacer. La función "seAbre()" podría ser algo como esto:

```
var ingresosDelLunes = [10, -5, 3, 0];
//Llamar a la función pasando el array
seAbre(ingresosDelLunes, 2);

function seAbre(arr, limite){
//Variable que contabiliza los que han llegado puntual o pronto
var cantidad = 0;
            //Recorrer el array
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                //Si el valor es 0 o menor ha llegado puntual o antes de tiempo
                if (arr[i] <= 0){
                    //Sumamos 1 al numero de personas que ha llegado bien
                    cantidad = cantidad + 1;
                }
            }
            //En funcion de la gente que necesites devolvemos true or false
            if (cantidad > limite) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
}
```

La finalidad de aperturas() no me queda clara. Quieres que haga exactamente lo mismo que seAbre() pero con varios días de golpe, vamos que pasando más parámetros. Puedes copiar la función seAbre() y hacerlo con todos los parámetros que necesites.

**EDITO:** Para la función apertura() puedes ir llamando a la función seAbre() y devolver los resultados en un array:

```
function apertura(arr1, arr2, arr3, limite){
//Creamos el array que va devolver el resultado     
var resultado = [];

//Llenamos el array con los resultados de cada dia
        resultado[0] = seAbre(arr1, limite);
        resultado[1] = seAbre(arr2, limite);
        resultado[2] = seAbre(arr3, limite);

        return resultado;
}
```

El resultado será un array que contenga algo parecido a esto:

> [true, true, false]

Comment: Utilice todo tu código (infinitamente agradecido, recién estoy empezando en JS), para aprobar todas las condiciones cambie la variable cantidad = 0 por 1 y dps en el for cambie <= 0 por 2. 

 seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 4)
 seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 3)
 seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 2)
 seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 1)
 seAbre([0, 0, 3, 0], 3)

Me pide usar la función aperturas ahora para que devuelva true o false, cómo decís que lo encare?

 aperturas([[0, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 3) 
 aperturas([[0, 0, -3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 4)

Comment: @TioPalta He editado la respuesta haciendo la función de aperturas();

Comment: Casi esta perfecto ya, pero me da un error. Qué significa esto? Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (solamente agregué el fragmento de código que vos editaste. Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda que me estás dando! Recién son mis primeros pasos.

Answer (score 1):

Para contar los elementos menores o iguales que 0 del array puedes utilizar el método `filter`

Para aplicar la función `seAbre` a todos los elementos del array puedes utilizar `map`:

```js
var ingresosDelLunes = [10, -5, 3, 0];
var ingresosDelMartes = [10, -5, -3, 0];
var ingresosDelMiercoles = [10, 2, 3, 0];
var ingresosDelJueves = [10, -5, -3, 0];
var ingresosDelViernes = [10, 4, 3, 8];

var numMinimo = 2;

function seAbre(datosDia, minimo){
  // Comprueba que el número de elementos <=0 sea >= que minimo
  return datosDia.filter(function(x) { return x<=0; }).length >= minimo;
}

console.log('Lunes: ' + seAbre(ingresosDelLunes, numMinimo));

function aperturas(datos, minimo){
  // Aplica la función seAbre a los datos de cada día
  return datos.map(function(d) { return seAbre(d, minimo); });
}

var datosSemana = [ingresosDelLunes, ingresosDelMartes, ingresosDelMiercoles, ingresosDelJueves, ingresosDelViernes];

console.log('Semana: ' + aperturas(datosSemana, numMinimo));
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la descripción de tu problema aquí está:

```html
 var ingresosDelLunes = [10, -5, 3, 0];
 var ingresosDelMartes = [-2, -1, 10];
 var ingresosDelMiercoles = [1, 15, 9, 15, 4];

 function apertura(arrays,estudiantes)
 {
  for(var i =0;i<arrays.length;i++)
  {
   var count = 0;

   if(arrays[i].length >= estudiantes)
   {
    for(var j = 0;j<arrays[i].length;j++)
    {
     if(arrays[i][j]<=0)
     {
      count = count+1;
     }
    }

    if(count>=estudiantes)
    {
     alert(true);
    }

    else
    {
     alert(false);
    }
   }

   else
   {
    alert(false);
   }
  }
 }

    apertura([ingresosDelLunes, ingresosDelMartes, ingresosDelMiercoles], 2);
```